# How to list All Databases using HiveContext in PySpark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6, hivecontext

I am trying to list all the databases using HiveContext in Spark 1.6 but its giving me just the default database.

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show()
```

```
+-------------+
|       result|
+-------------+
|      default|
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoking `SHOW DATABASES` in `sql` is the right approach in Spark < 2.0.

In Spark 2.0 or later you should use `pyspark.sql.catalog.Catalog.listDatabases`:

```
spark.catalog.listDatabases()
```

If you don't see expected databases it typically means one of two things:

- `hive-site.xml` is not present on Spark's classpath (see [Custom Hadoop/Hive Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration) in the [Spark Configuration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-configuration)).
- You initialized Spark without Hive support (i.e. using `SQLContext` instead of `HiveContext` in case of 1.6).

Comment: Thanks it worked after i added HiveContext, edited the question so the code is working